Kubuntu 24.04 Thunderbird - problem to send mail from any mail account
I installed Kubuntu 24.04 with Thunderbird SNAP and I can't send mail from any mail account (Gmail, Yahoo, Tiscali). Moreover some email are not displayed as that coming from my Linked-in account

do you face any errors? can you subscribe to any feeds with Thunderbird (to see if it's not a network issue)?

Can you try the thunderbird PPA instead of snap? https://askubuntu.com/q/1513445/124466

Many thanks, I solved installing the thunderbird PPA instead of snap. as from askubuntu.com/q/1513445/124466 –
Archisman Panigrahi

Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, accept the answer that you found most helpful. - From Review

@DavidDE This is a legitimate and unique self-answer.
