Snap and Thunderbird
I have used Thunderbird as my preferred mail client for many years. Recent upgrade to  24.04 from 22.04.4 seems to have changed storage options. Thunderbird 128.4.0esr(64bit)
I store my mail on my local server so that I can access it from a number of different computers on the same network.
​
Snap updates have not resolved the problem which persists, but I have now established exactly what is happening.
If I boot the computer at the beginning of the day Thunderbird starts but the network connection to my server is not made and the emails are not displayed. If I then reboot the computer Thunderbird again starts but the connection is made to the server correctly and all emails are available. Shutting down the computer at any time during the day and restarting, Thunderbird always connects correctly.
However, the next day the same problem returns - no connection on the first boot but on reboot everything connects correctly - even if there is an 8 or 9 hour delay between reboots.
So on each new day the problem returns. The problem seems to be somehow time/date related.
I realize that I can install a deb instead but this will not help in future if Snap is the continuing default install.
Any thoughts?
​

Do you automatically start thunderbird at boot? If so, try do delay thunderbirds start. Are other components of the network already up and running when you boot the first time? Check every component. My PC boots faster than my router, even with a HDD. Does thunderbird find the profile during first boot or starts with a new one?

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1513445/how-to-install-latest-version-of-thunderbird-as-a-traditional-deb-package-withou &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1513445/how-to-install-thunderbird-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-2
You can use the ppa, It is both Thunderbird & Firefox. You also have to reset priorities as shown or it will reinstall the Firefox or Thunderbird snap.
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04 &
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2024/08/install-thunderbird-deb-not-snap-in-ubuntu-24-04 &

Thanks so much for the responses.

I have tried both auto start and delaying the start of Thunderbird but the result is the same. I have also made sure the server has been accessed prior to starting Thunderbird - same result. On initial boot when I check the account settings I get the message "/run/user/1000/doc/5f5f8977/mail.xxxxxxx.com" is not a valid directory, however on reboot it accesses that local directory correctly and all mail is displayed.

Decided to delete Snap Thunderbird and move to ppa. Disaster. Only gives Thunderbird 115 and wont read old emails. Now considering reinstalling completely or moving to another distro after many years. Snap appears to me to be bloatware. Too much drama for someone in their eighties.
